# unable to paste stargazer table from R onto Excel

Tags: r, excel, stargazer

I am trying to copy paste stargazer table from Rstudio to Excel, and when I click on paste nothing happens.
Here is the syntax I am using
stargazer(caschool, type="text",median = TRUE, digits=2, title="CA schools dataset")

Comment: Hello bondgirl. Please do not take a picture of your screen to provide your code. Instead, provide your code in order to make it reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for responding - please edit your question to include this information instead of including the info in the comments.  If at all possible we would like a [mcve] ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can export it directly as an excel output in that way;

```
if(!require(xlsx)){
    install.packages('xlsx')
    library(xlsx)
}else{
    library(xlsx)
}

library(stargazer)

model <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + 1,iris)

stargazer_df <- data.frame(stargazer(model,type="text",median = TRUE, digits=2, title="CA schools dataset"))
names(stargazer_df) <- ''

write.xlsx(stargazer_df,file = "stargazer_output.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1")
```

Comment: After running the code,  this is the error we are getting                                                                                                                                    
  Error in write.xlsx(stargazer_df, file = "stargazer_output.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1") : 
  could not find function "write.xlsx"

Comment: @bondgirl you have to install `xlsx` package at first

Comment: Here is the warning I am getting when I used the command install.packages("xlsx") Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.microsoft.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1:
  cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\scarl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEpxxnu\file5174453c558b', reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: @bondgirl the question of last error's cause is something different from your main question.